# FOR loop for iterating through Registry hives

Tags: batch-file, registry

I'm working on a script to modify multiple registry keys at the same time. I'm trying to find a way to iterate through the sub-folders under a single registry hive, and run a specific command for each one found. The hive structure looks something like this:

```
HKLM
    -Blah
        -BLahBlah
            -Databases
                -DB1
                -DB2
                -DB3
```

What I want to do is basically set a new variable for the DB name, run a script for that specific folder, then move on to the next.

Comment: This is simply not good enough, especially from somebody not brand new to this site. Provide your code and we will try to help you with it where you become stuck. In addition, the registry locations are unlikely to be protected under some law, so please provide the real full keys, complete with their relevant data, by updating your initial question.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=*" %%# in  ('reg query  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\BLAH\Databases') do echo %%#`  ?

Comment: @Compo Sorry, but that's not a very constructive answer. I didn't feel comfortable giving out the actual registry information or code, because it contains proprietary information unique to our environment.

Comment: @npocmaka thank you, that worked great.

Comment: @user3492006 - then I'll add it as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [**`REG`**](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) command you can query or edit registry entries. To process them one by one you can use [**`FOR`**](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) command:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%# in ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\BLAH\Databases') do echo %%#
```